# How to fetch all the details of the object using Jsoup library and save it to the bean?

Tags: java, html, xpath, jsoup, html-parsing

**Here I'm Scraping the site https://hamrobazaar.com/c6-apparels-and-accessories and i want to store all the sub-categories details in a bean and print them. If i got the details of object accordingly than this also would be much help.**

**Example:**

[image: Image from the same site i.e https://hamrobazaar.com/c6-apparels-and-accessories]

**I want to Scrape Name of the Mask as Kn95 Mask (fda Certified), description as We are Seller..., seller name as Birodh Pokhrel, Address as Damak-5,Damak, price as 210, date, and type as Brand New**

**If you are good at Jsoup, and Xpath. Please help me to obtain this. Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

For the XPath part (`jsoup` doesn't support it, so maybe you can try with `xsoup`) :

Some selectors to grab the details from the ads, including the one with yellow background which stays the same for each page. (article title, description, seller, address, price, item condition) :

```
//font[@style]/b
//b[.="Seller:"]/preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]
//b[.="Seller:"]/following-sibling::a
//b[.="Seller:"]/following-sibling::font
//b[starts-with(.,"Rs.")]
//b[starts-with(.,"Rs.")]/following-sibling::font
```

Number of elements for each detail : `21`

Some selectors to grab the details from the ads, excluding the one with yellow background which stays the same for each page. (article title, description, seller, address, price, item condition) :

```
//font[@style][not(ancestor::table[@id])]/b
//b[.="Seller:"][not(ancestor::table[@id])]/preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]
//b[.="Seller:"][not(ancestor::table[@id])]/following-sibling::a
//b[.="Seller:"][not(ancestor::table[@id])]/following-sibling::font
//b[not(ancestor::table[@id])][starts-with(.,"Rs.")]
//b[not(ancestor::table[@id])][starts-with(.,"Rs.")]/following-sibling::font
```

Number of elements for each detail : `20`

Side note : be careful with item condition. Some ads are missing this field. So, the number of elements could be lower than 20 or 21.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but i prefer to move to HtmlUnit for this purpose and it finally works.